# Format PHP code using a coding standard

Tags: php, eclipse-pdt

It is possible to configure Eclipse PDT to format my php code after a standard like MySource or Zend?

Answer (score 0):

You looking for code indentation .

I hope this may help you

http://drupal.org/node/75242

https://github.com/ginatrapani/ThinkUp/wiki/Developer-Guide:-Setting-Up-Eclipse-PDT

Answer (score 0):

You can, except maybe max line length. Preferences->PHP->Code Style->Formatter will change indention.

Preferences->General->Workspace will change text file formatting (i.e; line termination)

Preferences->PHP->Editor->Typing there is an option for closing PHP tag